# Convert order of array of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to change the order of php array of array.

```
    $arrKeysWithoutValues = array("id", "mobile", "stockCode");

    $new_data = array();
    foreach ($arrKeysWithoutValues as $key) {
        //$list is array of array
        $new_data[$key] = array_column($list, $key);
    }
    //what I received is as follows 
    //Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 4967 [1] => 4965 ) [mobile] => Array ( [0] => ****0030008 [1] => ****0030009 ) [stockCode] => Array ( [0] => sh600036 [1] => sh600036 ) )

    //what I need is as follows
    //Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4967 [mobile] => ****0030008 [stockCode] => sh600036 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4965 [mobile] => ****0030009 [stockCode] => sh600036 ) )
```

What I received and what I needed is as in above comments. How can I solve this?

Sample structure of the list is as follows.

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4967 [stockCode] => sh600036 [mobile] => ****0030008 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4965 [stockCode] => sh600036 [mobile] => ****0030009 ) )`

Comment: can you show sample structure of `$list`.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample structure of $list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't touch and push the keys.

```
$new_data[$key] = array_column($list, $key);
      //   ^ this will yield different results
```

You use the order array and flip them into `keys`, then `array_merge` it with the original list, so then you keep the desired order. Like so:

```
$new_data = array();
$keys = array_flip($arrKeysWithoutValues); // flip and turn it to keys
foreach ($list as $l) {
    $new_data[] = array_merge($keys, $l);
                  // ^^ merge them
}
```